# Powers generate monomials

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, commutative-algebra

What is a reference in the literature for the following fact?

Let $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. Then every monomial in $A$ of degree $n$ may be written as a linear combination of $n$th powers.

For example, $a \cdot b = \frac{1}{2} ((a+b)^2-a^2-b^2)$ for $n=2$. For $n=3$, we have $ab^2=\frac{1}{6} ((a+b)^3+(a-b)^3-2a^3)$, hence also $abc=\frac{1}{2} (a(b+c)^2-a b^2-a c^2)$ may be generated.

Of course it suffices to consider $A=\mathbb{Q}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$ and to write $T_1 \cdot \dotsc \cdot T_n$ as a linear combination of $n$th powers.

PS: I'm not looking for a proof, I'm looking for a reference.

PPS: It seems to be known as the *Waring decomposition*.

Answer (score 1):

The following argument, if correct, is not original.

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be indeterminates, let $V_m$ be the $\mathbb Q$-vector space formed by the degree $m$ homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb Q[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, and let $W\subset V$ be the subspace generated by the $\ell^m$ with $\ell$ in $V_1$.

It suffices to show $W=V_m$.

Put 
$$
D_i:=\frac\partial{\partial X_i}\ .
$$
The bilinear form $(f,g)\mapsto f(D)g(X)$ on $V_m$ being non-degenerate, it suffices to show that if $f$ in $V_m$ be such that $f(D)\ell(X)^m=0$ for all $\ell$ in $V_1$, then $f=0$. This is straightforward.

**EDIT 1.** Here are more details about the last sentence. If we set, using multi-index notation, 
$$
f(D)=\sum_\alpha a_\alpha\,D^\alpha,\quad \ell(X)=\sum_i b_i\,X_i,
$$
then we get, by the Binomial Theorem,
$$
0=f(D)\ell(X)^m=m!\ f(b).
$$
for all $b$ in $\mathbb Q^n$, which implies indeed $f=0$.

**EDIT 2.** Let's check the equality $f(D)\ell(X)^m=m!\ f(b)$ above. We have 
$$
f(D)\ell(X)^m=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}a_\alpha D^\alpha\binom m\beta b^\beta X^\beta=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}a_\alpha\binom m\beta b^\beta D^\alpha X^\beta
$$
$$
=\sum_\alpha a_\alpha\binom m\alpha b^\alpha\alpha!=m!\sum_\alpha a_\alpha b^\alpha=m!f(b).
$$ 
Throughout this post, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $n$-indices of length $m$.

Comment: I use the abbreviations $X:=(X_1,\dots,X_n),\ X^\alpha:=X_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots X_n^{\alpha_n},\dots$. Also note the equality $D^\alpha\, X^\beta=\delta_{\alpha\beta}\,\alpha!$ - I should have said [Multinomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) instead of Binomial Theorem... - Thanks for letting me know if there is anything unclear or incorrect.

Comment: What does $f(D)$ mean? Also, is there a more direct proof?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg - The notation $f(D)$ means $f(D_1,\dots,D_n)$. That's the only proof I know.